# dependencies without using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have two files

In project1 have a file named test.java:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 sayHello();
}

public static void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("MyTest says hello!");
}}
```

In project2 have a file named test2.java:

`public class test2`

```
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 sayHello();
}

public static void sayHello() {
System.out.println("MyTest2 says hello!");
}}
```

Here i need to link up the class file of test(which is in project 1) to test2(which is my project2) without using maven. how do i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using eclipse then right click on `project2>properties>java build path>projects>` add project 1.